# How to send requests to MongoDB using JavaScript (front-end app) with Authentication?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, rest, authentication, pymongo

Is there a tutorial or a procedure that explains how should I connect to a MongoDB database using JavaScript, AJAX and jQuery with authentication?

Using PyMongo in Python, I am able to give the following values and connect with a remote MongoDB that has authentication.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
uri = "mongodb://username:password@host:port/?authSource=database"
client = MongoClient(uri)
```

However, I need to connect to a remote MongoDB using JavaScript (front-end app).

I tried the following, but unable to connect successfully.

```
var mongo_uri = "http://host:port/database/collections";
$.ajax({
    url: mongo_uri,
    data: JSON.stringify({
        <some-data-here>
    }),
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("success");
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
})
```

How should I authenticate and do post/get via JavaScript?

Kindly help me as I'm new to this.

Comment: You need a web server. What web server are you using? (i.e. django)

Comment: What if I don't have access to the web server that MongoDB runs? Like in MongoLab, I can send a direct post/get request using a single URL and an API key right? In my case, I have a username and password as the authentication mechanism.

Comment: Mongo itself doesn't have the features of mlab. You can either create an api with a web server or use JavaScript to access it directly without a fetch/ajax request.

Comment: How to do the second thing that you have mentioned? Kindly help.

Comment: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-articles/nodekoarticle1.html

Comment: Can this be done from client-side? I mean, can I use this MongoDB Node.js github repo on client-side (front-end app)?

Comment: I guess I don't know what you're asking. If you are accessing the db locally then you can just do a node app. If you are accessing it over the wire then you'll need to implement some sort of web server or service like mlab.